# Find the mean of values with same keys and find the most repeated one

Tags: python

So I have an input.txt file like this:

```
2,1
.,1
2,1
1,1
2,1
3,1
3,1
```

There is a . in there because I parsed a long decimal number and that is the decimal point.

I want to find the mean of the numbers on the left, which would be 2+2+1+2+3+3/6 and find the most repeated digit which would be 2.

Im trying to run a loop over the text file of the form:
`for line in text`

But it when I print(line) it only prints 2 and not the whole 2,1 which I can then separate using line.split(',').

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: `for line in text.splitlines():`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv` and `statistics.mean/mode` with a comprehension:

```
from statistics import mean, mode
from csv import reader

with open('input.txt') as f:
    vals = [int(i) for i,_ in reader(f) if i.isnumeric())]
    avg = mean(vals)
    most_freq = mode(vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use numpy to load the file and get the mean as well and most frequent value:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.genfromtxt('file.txt', delimiter=',')[:, 0]
mean = np.mean(values) 
mostFrequent = np.argmax(np.bincount(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

```
import pandas as pd


filename = "test.txt"
```

**Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, na_values=".")
```

**Demo**

```
df
```

[image]

```
df[0].mean()
# 2.1666666666666665

df[0].mode()[0]
# 2.0

df.describe()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Start from here:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('input.txt', delimiter=',')
print(my_data)
```

Then look into [numpy.place](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html).